# Typescript - What is the better way to cast the return value of Object.keys()?

Tags: typescript, casting

I think the code will speak by itself, so here it is:

```js
type myType = "a" | "b" | "c";
type myMappedType = { [str in myType]: number };

const values: myMappedType = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

const keys = Object.keys as <T>(o: T) => Extract<keyof T, string>[];
const keys2 = Object.keys as <T>(o: T) => Array<keyof T>;

Object.keys(values) // string[]
keys(values) // myType[]
keys2(values) // myType[]
```

What is the better way to cast the return value of Object.keys()?

- Should I use the `keys` or the `keys2` implementation? Or even another one?
- Which one is better and why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `keys` version is more correct. The main difference is `keys2` will include number and [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) keys in the resulting type, but the symbol keys will not be in the result of `Object.keys`.

I'd include `number` in the extract type though:

```
const keys = Object.keys as <T>(o: T) => Extract<keyof T, string | number>[];
```

`Object.keys` will return numeric keys (as strings), but they will be missing from the return type if you don't make this change.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I was also thinking about including number in the extract version TBH, but wasn't sure of it.

Comment: I will be waiting a bit more to see if someone has a different opinion on this before accepting your answer as final. Thanks again!

Comment: A snag with `Extract<keyof T, string | number>` is that `Object.keys({0: 0})[0]` is `"0"` and not `0`.  If you really have numeric keys you need to think more carefully about what you're doing...

Comment: This can then be an improvement over Object.keys, providing a number type.

Comment: Can someone please tell me what is being done here 
`const keys = Object.keys as <T>(o: T) => Extract<keyof T, string | number>[];`
are we converting the implementation of Object.keys method ?

Answer (score 0):

Even using `Record<myType, number>`, `Object.keys` will return a `string[]`. If you were to use an ES6 `Map`, however,

```
type myType = "a" | "b" | "c";

const mapValues = new Map<myType, number>(
    [
     ['a', 1]
     , ['b', 2]
     , ['c', 3]
    ]
)

mapValues.keys() // IterableIterator<myType>
```

Map contructors are a tad bit less ergonomic than object literals, but they seem to work better with TypeScript's typing. I tried in vain to dig up an old thread about object typing that lays out the weird edge cases with it.

Comment: I am already using interfaces so using maps is not an option for me.